# move up method in checkers game in java

Tags: java

I was reading this program that I saw in class relating to a checkers game this is the method that is called getup.

```
int rowUp = row-1;
        if(column == 0 && row != 0)
                { 
            for(int i = column; i < column+2; i++)
                        { 
                if(gameData[column][row] != 0 && gameData[i][rowUp] != 0)
                                {
                    if(canJump(column, row, i, rowUp) == true)                                            {
                        int jumpCol = jumpPos(column, row, i, rowUp)[0];
                        int jumpRow = jumpPos(column, row, i, rowUp)[1];
                        availablePlays[jumpCol][jumpRow] = 1;//makes it available 
                    }
                }
                else if(baseGameData[i][rowUp] == 1 && gameData[i][rowUp] == 0)
                    availablePlays[i][rowUp] = 1;
            }
        }
```

the Part that I dont understand is:

```
int jumpCol = jumpPos(column, row, i, rowUp)[0];
int jumpRow = jumpPos(column, row, i, rowUp)[1];
```

I really dont get what the col row i and row up parameters are and what the [0] or [1] mean. and how can this even be assigned to an int

Comment: A method `jumpPos` is called, an array is returned, `[0]` gets the first element of that array and `[1]` gets the second element from that array and since it is assigned to an `int` the array must contain `int`s. Unless we see the code for the `jumpPos` method we can only assume what the parameters mean.

Comment: Agree with @csmckelvey.  One point to make though, those two calls are exactly duplicated - except for indexes.  Understanding what those calls do is useful, but that code should not be emulated as-is.

Answer (score 0):

The int jumpCol can be assigned because its the *position* of the spot in the checkers game. For example, if you had a row of names (Alex, Allen, George, Greg). *REMEMBER: THE FIRST ONE OF AN ARRAY IS ALWAYS 0.* In programming, we could assume that Alex would be at position 0 (or [0]), Allen would at [1], George would be position [2], and Greg would be position [3]. Technically there would still be 4 (0,1,2,3) but we start off with 0 instead of 1. So, you are technically assigning the position of the item. In our small example, you would be assigning the location of the item instead of the actually item. Sorry, that might of sounded a bit confusing. To shorten it, you are assigning the integer to Allen. But in reality your actually assigning the integer to the location. So because Allen is in [1] (position 1) your integer would have the value of 1, instead of "Allen.

Hope this helped.